# Why wasn't Baymax destroyed in the fire?

Tags: big-hero-6

Baymax was in the fire. So why didn't he burn? Tadashi never brought him out so he should have been destroyed in the fire. Why wasn't he? It's possible someone else brought him out, but is there another explanation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Was Baymax actually being exhibited at the university's showcase? If nobody brought him out of the university, then the other logical explanation is that he wasn't *in* the university to start with.

Comment: Baymax wasn't in the fire.

Comment: @DavidW Is it worth making that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Tadashi never took Baymax to the exhibition.**  (He was already in SFIT; he didn't need to compete for entrance like Hiro did.)  If Baymax *had* been taken to the exhibition and someone brought it out, Baymax wouldn't have been forgotten about and ignored, stuffed in a corner by Tadashi's bed.

When Hiro drops the segment of his dueling robot on his foot in the room he and Tadashi shared, and says "Ouch," he triggers Baymax's care mode.  Hiro is surprised by Baymax's sudden appearance; he has obviously forgotten or not thought about it.  If Baymax had been at the exhibition and been rescued it wouldn't surprise Hiro in this way.  (If Baymax were a creation of his brother's that *had* been saved from the fire, it would be much more emotionally important.)

Comment: But Tadashi had introduced Hiro to Baymax earlier in the film when he also introduced Hiro to his friends at the SFIT lab before the microbot-development montage. Hiro's well aware by the time after the exhibition  fire that Baymax is a medical-care robot and even gushed about his construction and AI capability when they first met.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - You're right. They've met before.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Sorry, I didn't recall that.  I just remember Hiro being nonplussed by Baymax's sudden appearance; now that you mention it I do vaguely recall him talking about the titanium skeleton.  But did Hiro see Baymax demonstrate his "bedside manner?"

Comment: @Valorum I'm still certain that Baymax wouldn't have been forgotten in a corner if it had been rescued from the fire; do you think it's worth trying to rewrite the answer on that basis?

Comment: @DavidW He did! Hiro had a scrape or something from his bot-fighting earlier, Baymax applies a spray and gives Hiro a sucker, and Hiro is "satisfied with his care". And nothing to be sorry about, I rewatched this movie last week and a friend happened to be playing it in the background for her kids while we were gaming the other day so it's fresh lol. Also, the microbots montage probably took a while and Tadashi might've brought Baymax home to work on him or something. He's a lot more portable and easier to work on than the other students' projects.

Answer (score 1):

The SFIT Tech Showcase was intended to showcase *new inventions* by *potential undergraduates*.

> **The Tech Showcase**
>
> Every year, San Fransokyo Tech prepares for a new
> influx of students with its traditional battle of the
> brains—the SFIT Tech Showcase. The event attracts
> VIPs of the science world, as well as stars of big
> business seeking to spot talent and steal a few ideas.
> Dreams become reality here, or end up shattered.
>
> The showcase is a
> buzzing live show, where
> prospective students
> share technology that
> might just change
> the future.
>
> <sub><sup>[Big Hero 6 - The Essential Guide](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/23984673-big-hero-6)</sup></sub>

Since Tadashi is already a student at the school (and not even in his first year), he likely wouldn't have been eligible to enter. Additionally, the professor is already well aware of Baymax, having seen it months ago and wouldn't be particularly impressed at seeing it again.

> Tadashi came home the next day and stapled an SFIT poster over one of
> Hiro’s bot-fighting posters. **It announced SFIT’s annual Tech
> Showcase—those entrants with the best tech would win admission to the
> school.**
>
> Hiro read it and looked at Tadashi in disbelief.
>
> “You come up with something that blows Callaghan away and you’re in,”
> Tadashi said. “But it’s gotta be great.”
>
> Hiro stared at the poster, smiling. “Trust me, it will be,” he said,
> knowing this was his big chance. He rolled his chair to his desk and
> confidently set about designing the most awesome tech project SFIT had
> ever seen.
>
> <sub><sup>[*Baymax - Official Junior Novelisation*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25979763-big-hero-6-junior-novelization)</sup></sub>

**Baymax wasn't at the showcase when the fire happened.** Depending on which source you refer to, it was either in Tadashi and Hiro's room (tucked into his suitcase) when the fire happened or subsequently returned to his family after the showcase fire, presumably when his crap was cleared out of the lab space he no longer needs.

The Essential Guide notes that Tadashi's belongings are "*untouched since the fire*". The official novelisation notes Hiro's surprise at seeing the bot unfold...

> Hiro hit a button, and silence filled the room. He sighed as his eyes moved across his desk, stopping as they fell on a letter from SFIT. Anger and despair filled him, and he grabbed the letter and tossed it in the trash. He picked up Megabot, his fighting bot, and the bottom of it fell off, landing on his foot. “Ow!” he yelled.
> Hiro hopped up and down for a minute, and then he saw something moving on Tadashi’s side of the room. He was stunned for a moment. He stared as a white shape rose and began to take form. It was Baymax!
>
> Once Baymax had fully inflated, he shuffled and shimmied his enormous white body to Hiro’s side of the room. His big belly and behind knocked over books and lamps along the way. “Hello,” he said finally. “I am Baymax, your personal health-care companion.”
>
> <sup>[*Baymax - Official Junior Novelisation*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25979763-big-hero-6-junior-novelization)</sup>

...but the junior reader implies that Baymax was returned to the family after the showcase occurred.

> Something moved near Tadashi's
> bed. Baymax, Tadashi’s robot, inflated to
> full size. **He had been in the room since
> the showcase!** Hiro's cry of pain had
> made him activate.
>
> Hiro was so shocked to see him, he
> tripped.
>
> <sup>[Big Hero 6 - Hiro to the Rescue](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23552092-big-hero-6)</sup>

Either way, there would have been no good reason for Baymax to have been at the Showcase event.